# NProduct fails strangely

Tags: numerics

For `{n, 1, 24}` I get an instantaneous answer for `{n, 1, 25}` runs without stopping! Then I tried `{n, 2, 25}`, and that runs fine!?

```
m = 1;
rho = .5;
ell = 1.2;
x = .3;
e0[x_, r_] := (Sqrt[(x - m)^2 + r^2] + Sqrt[(x + m)^2 + r^2] - 
    2 m)/(Sqrt[(x - m)^2 + r^2] + Sqrt[(x + m)^2 + r^2] + 2 m)
NProduct[e0[x + n ell, rho] e0[x - n ell, rho] Exp[(4 m)/(n ell)], {n,
   1, 24}]
NProduct[e0[x + n ell, rho] e0[x - n ell, rho] Exp[(4 m)/(n ell)], {n,
   1, 25}]

Out[195]= 0.616349

Out[196]= $Aborted
```

Comment: I suspect that `NProduct` is trying to be too clever somehow. In your case, though, you can just calculate the values in a Table, then take the product: `Times@@Table[e0[x + n ell, rho] e0[x - n ell, rho] Exp[(4 m)/(n ell)], {n, 1, 26}]`.

Comment: It uses some sort of extrapolation to approximate the tail when the number of factors gets large. It's not just a multiplying routine. It's mainly to apply a numerical method to approximate the product, but it doesn't bother with the method for small products. I'd suggest `Product[..., Method -> "Procedural"]` instead of `NProduct`, or `Product[N[factor],..., Method -> "Procedural"]` if the `factor` is exact and you do not want an exact result.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `NProduct` is trying some analytical tricks if n>=25. If you define the terms to be numerical, you get a result, but you will note a short delay:

```
Clear[f]
m = 1;
rho = .5;
ell = 1.2;
x = .3;
e0[x_, r_] := (Sqrt[(x - m)^2 + r^2] + Sqrt[(x + m)^2 + r^2] - 
    2 m)/(Sqrt[(x - m)^2 + r^2] + Sqrt[(x + m)^2 + r^2] + 2 m)

f[n_ /; NumericQ[n]] = 
  e0[x + n ell, rho] e0[x - n ell, rho] Exp[(4 m)/(n ell)] // Simplify;

NProduct[(f[n]), {n, 1, 25}]

(*0.616322*)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  It works for me as well.  Even works for {n,1,Infinity} which is what I really want!